# LAMPP Database Server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, lampp

I successfully installed lampp in my Ubunto Server and connect to mysql server in the remote PC. After I added the security settings I wasn't able to connect to database anymore.

Badly needed your ideas. I'm a newbie for this one.

How can I connect to the mysql database remotely?

Comment: Could you please mention what security settings you applied?

Comment: lampp and phpmyadmin setting.

Comment: But what exactly you changed? which files? Details would be helpful to detect problem and also mention what error are you getting while connecting from remote PC.

Comment: `<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
 Order deny,allow
 #Deny from all
 Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
  fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
  fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>`

Comment: Add in your question, by clicking on edit button below your question.